The skirt tranparency bug
I want to know how to make it render all of the skirt because it keep being like this i don't know what to do the skirt keep messing thing up now it tranparency issue how to fix this?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
